# dotnet build - Unable to find package - Private nuget server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I am trying to create Self Contained Deployment of a .net core console app (netcoreapp2.0). The company has their own private Nuget server where they host all of their custom Nuget packages. I am referencing one of these packages in my console app. When I run "dotnet build -r win10-x64" I get an error that states "Unable to find package". The package it cannot find is on their private Nuget server. How/where do I tell it to look in private Nuget repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out my own answer. I went here C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

In the "packageSources" section, I added:

```
<add key="MyCustomName" value="http://MyPrivateNugetRepoUrl" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One may also do it using Visual Studio's GUI :

1. Right click on the solution, choose "Manage nuget packages for the solution..."
2. Click on the little gear icon near "package source" in the upper-right corner.
3. In this window, you may add (and also activate/deactivate) nuget package sources.

Comment: Good point, this is how you hook up to a private nugget source but when running "dotnet build..." it did not know how to find that source. (At least for me)

Answer (score 0):

While building with Visual Studio it's pretty easy to configure as VS gives UI to configure private NuGet server

[image: private nuget in Visual studio]

You can build the project using the command line

```
dotnet publish <path to .csproj file> -c Release -r linux-x64 -f netcoreapp2.2 --output <path to output build folder>
```

This works fine when run on a machine having VS installed and private NuGet configured through VS.

But this fails in case run on a machine not having VS installed.

For such cases, you can find nuget.config file and add private NuGet server in package sources
[image]

You can find NuGet config file in `C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Nuget` if dotnet is installed explicitly
if VS is installed `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config`